# How can I specify the app deployment to be in another folder using cloud build?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have my app in a folder called `client`, how can I create a trigger that will specify the app deployment workflow to execute on that folder instead?

My cloudbuild.yaml file is also in that folder and has this content:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args:
    - |
      cd ../client
      gcloud app deploy
timeout: "1600s"
```

The error is as such:

```
ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'cd ../client
```

My file directory:

- main

  - .gitignore
  - LICENSE
  - README.md
  - client

    - app.yaml
    - cloudbuild.yaml

Answer (score 3):

`gcloud` is not bash or similar, then you cannot execute something like `cd ../client`

I'd suggest to use [`dir`](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#dir) in your step, then it will use the directory specified as the working directory:

```yaml
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  dir: client/
  args:
    - app
    - deploy
timeout: "1600s"
```

You can change the path, just be aware about the full structure of your files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually execute the directory change then you need to change your entry point to bash. Take a look at the second example here: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts

The gcloud tool will also take a parameter for which app.yaml to deploy so you could just add the desired path to your existing args. You can find the gcloud app deploy reference here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy